# I can't get $_POST parameters in php once website SSL done

Tags: php, ssl

I have a simple php code as follow:

```
<?
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

This worked for non-SSL domain before I have done SSL.
But it doesn't work after I have done SSL.

After SSL done, it works with `https://` well, however, I like to use old `http://` call which was working well also.

Because I already published the webapp using the `http://` call, and can't modify the API call parts.

Any help?

In Addition, I test the API in postman with POST option, 
it works with only https://example.com/api.php, but doesn't work with http://example.com/api.php and it just returns empty array value.

Comment: Firstly, `$_POST` is an array, so you can't use `echo`. Use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some redirect from http to https? If you are under https and post to http, the web server will redirect the user to https. Redirects are using GET, which means that the POST data gets lost during the redirect. You need to post the data using the same schema as you're currently on.

Comment: can we take a look at your code?

Comment: That's all of my code!

Comment: Luis, what Isaac and Magnus are saying is that the form where action is specified should use the https now as well.  The form is probably being posted to http, which then redirects.

Comment: Wait, does it work on `https` or on `http`? Your question is a little ambivalent in this. Also, if this is really all your code, then you are ommitting something else, because this code works both on HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, I clarified on which it works or not. And, no it doesn't work for BOTH, only works for one Protocol.

Comment: print_r($_POST[]);
Try this.

Comment: @vivek, I advise you to learn how to read contents carefully.

Comment: @Luis thanks for your advise :)

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` is an array of post values, it shouldn't work on `https` or `http` either, PHP will return this message

> Notice: Array to string conversion

To solve this problem you should use :

```
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I meant print_r() or var_dump(), this is not related with echo or print_r, just https, and http, hope you focus on main issue.